# I am unable to get the correct answer to print out : "Sarah's favorite language is : C " when the languages only contain a single language

Tags: python

```
favorite_languages = {
    "jen": ["python", "ruby"],
    "sarah": "c",
    "edward": ["ruby", "go"],
    "phil": ["python", "haskell"],
}

for names, languages in favorite_languages.items():

    if len(languages) > 1:
        print(f"\n{names.title()}'s favorite languages are:")
        for language in languages:
            print(f"\t{language.title()}")
    else:
        print(f"\n{names.title()}'s favorite language is: {language.title()} ")
```

Comment: "sarah"'s languages don't 'contain' a single language, it just is a single language. Use `["c"]` instead

Comment: Try to change to: `"sarah": ["c"],`

Comment: Use `languages` instead of `language` in your `else` clause.

Comment: i still get the same results with the added bracket. It sprinted : Sarah's favorite language is Ruby instead of C

Comment: @Grismar That's not the issue here, since the result of `len(languages)` is the same for `["c"]` and `"c"`.

Comment: use languages still generate the same results...

Comment: basically the output for sarah is incorrect. it display "ruby" instead of "c"

Comment: @AKX note that it only works because C happens to be a single letter long, if Sarah happened to only like Haskell, that won't fly.

Comment: @Grismar Yes, I'm aware of that. OP has a strange heterogeneous data format, but changing it to `["c"]` still won't fix the problem (which is a leaking name).

Comment: @AKX So.... in addition to changing the data type to be a list, they need to print `languages[0].title()` instead of `language.title()` - but since I only wrote a comment and not an answer, it makes little sense to respond as if the comment wasn't valid (it was) or complain that it wasn't complete (it was a comment, not an answer)

Comment: Thanks for all the advices and help! Deeply appreciate it!

Comment: If one of the answers below solves your problem, @Juz, feel free to click the checkmark next to it, so that the question no longer appears as unanwered - or write your own answer if you've found a better way, and accept that.

Comment: @Grismar, Thanks for your guidance. This is my first posting and still finding my way to learn. Thank you and good day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code needs two simple fixes:

```
favorite_languages = {
    "jen": ["python", "ruby"],
    "sarah": ["c"],
    "edward": ["ruby", "go"],
    "phil": ["python", "haskell"],
}

for names, languages in favorite_languages.items():
    if len(languages) > 1:
        print(f"\n{names.title()}'s favorite languages are:")
        for language in languages:
            print(f"\t{language.title()}")
    else:
        print(f"\n{names.title()}'s favorite language is: {languages[0].title()} ")
```

Note that Sarah now likes a list of one language (`["c"]`), which will work as well if she liked a language with a longer name like `["haskell"]`.

And since there's only one print statement, it prints the first langauge in `languages` with `{languages[0].title()}`.

Answer (score -1):

`language` has been assigned by the `for language in languages` loop during the last iteration of the outer loop to whatever was the last favorite language of the last person.

In fact, if you comment Jen out of the dict altogether, you'll get a

```
NameError: name 'language' is not defined
```

because the `for language in languages:` for loop has never been executed when reaching the Sarah case, and that name is not a thing. (As an aside, in a function, this would result in an unbound local error instead.)

Even if it's semantically silly-sounding, this is fixed by changing

```
print(f"\n{names.title()}'s favorite language is: {language.title()} ")
```

to

```
print(f"\n{names.title()}'s favorite language is: {languages.title()} ")
```

since `languages` is either the single language or the list of languages for a person.

Comment: A bit complicated, since the use of a side-effect of a loop execution in another branch seems accidental here, but your solution also doesn't work, try changing Sarah's favourite language to "haskell"

Comment: It works for OP's data and OP's issue. It explains why OP was seeing Jen's last favorite language.

Comment: That's like saying just printing "C" when you notice "Sarah" fixes the problem - when a solution is clearly flawed for valid test data (like Sarah liking Haskell and only Haskell), it's wrong.

Comment: @Grismar What if op's data is meant to be like that? You'd want `if isinstance(languages, list)` instead of modifying the data...

Comment: Their acceptance of the provided answer seems to indicate otherwise - regardless, that's not the solution provided, so I'm not entirely certain what hill you're looking to die on here?

Answer (score -1):

Print  languages instead of language

```
for names, languages in favorite_languages.items():
    if len(languages) > 1:
        print(f"\n{names.title()}'s favorite languages are:")
        for language in languages:
            print(f"\t{language.title()}")
    else:
        print(f"\n{names.title()}'s favorite language is: {languages} ")
```

Comment: This doesn't work, try changing Sarah's favourite language to `"haskell"`